# Esri map working locally but not showing on azure

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I really don't know how to describe the issue here, I'm using Angular 9 and I'm loading an esri map.

Locally everything is working fine, the map and widgets are being displayed and nothing is wrong.

When I publish my application into Azure. I'm getting the following errors:

[image: Error]

I really couldn't find any solution on SO neither on esri question page. Anyone have any idea about what's happening?? Or anyone have encountered this issue before??

PS: It's like he's loading widgets, and other data from my backend URL. But this should not happen!

Comment: have you done something to the default Attribution widget?

Comment: No I haven't done anything, and it's not just the attribution widget, all the widget I'm using are giving the same error. And as I mentioned locally everything is working fine. The problem is only on an Azure App Service

Comment: How are you building your application?  How are you publishing it?  It seems something is wrong with the way your app is bundling the esri modules.  What does the build process look like?  I'm not an angular dev, but based on that error message, that's where I'd start looking.  Does this error occur on your local machine when running a build and serving it locally?

Comment: Is your web server set up to serve *.json files? Does it work if you try to load that JSON file directly in the browser?